# Nested singular resource, not showing up in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a search and replace controller, with just an index action. Since it's meant to go under one of my restful controllers created by a scaffold, i setup the following in the routes file:

```
resources :sites do
  resource :search_and_replace, only: [:index]
end
```

However, it does not appear when I run rake routes. If I switch to resources, it does. But the method name is `site_search_and_replace_index`. The pluralization of resource doesn't feel right either, since this is not around multiple records in a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index` action doesn't exist in a singular resource. This makes sense if you think of the meaning of the action: index of what, there's only one resource? Use `show` instead:

```
resources :sites do
  resource :search_and_replace, only: [:show]
end
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I imagined it was something simple and logical i was missing, thanks very much.

Comment: @agmcleod I've been bitten by this as well, standing puzzled in front of my monitor :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to have search and replace as a resource? There might be other options that are more useful: [Adding more restful actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: Interesting idea. But this isn't searching the site. What it actually will do is search the content of children of children to the site model. I essentially have the following models: Site -> ElementType ->  Element. The element objects are what will be searched in the particular site. It is a thought though to perhaps apply that to the element controller instead. I could add it as a nested aspect to the sites/elements: http://pastie.org/2605785

Comment: @agmcleod imho, 2 levels of nesting is when helpers & such start to be unwieldy, I usually stick to 1 maximum. This is even stated in the rails docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting

Comment: @agmcleod well, I just thought that search and replace sounded more like a name of an action than a resource. Would it fit better to have it as an action on the elementType controller then?

Comment: Hmm interesting. Actually just noticed i wasn't even using the nested elements resource there, just sites/elements. Ran all my tests after removing it, and they pass.